# Swift initialization stored property outside init method of class issue

Tags: swift, swift2

I have an swift class

```
class ApplicationManager {

var fanMode: FanMode

init()
{
  self.applyDefaultSettings()
}

func applyDefaultSettings()
{
  if let unwrappedFanMode = userDefaults.valueForKey(Consts.kStoredFanMode) as? FanMode {
    self.fanMode = unwrappedFanMode
  }
}

}
```

The code above throws this issue:

```
Use of 'self' in method call 'applyDefaultSettings' before all stored properties are initialized
```

What should I do here? So as message say I need to initialize all stored properties before I call any other method of class. So it means in init method I should initialize at least fanMode property. But I want to have method that apply kind of default settings for my properties to provide simple readability and clean code architecture. But maybe it's ok to use initializer of class to init all needed fields.

Comment: Look, in your code logic possible situation when fanMode will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can do it by using this code:

```
var fanMode: FanMode = {
    if let unwrappedFanMode = userDefaults.valueForKey(Consts.kStoredFanMode) as? FanMode {
        return unwrappedFanMode
    } else {
        return FanMode()//some default implementation
    }
}()
```

It is readable as You want.

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple documentation, Swift does not allow you to left uninitialised variables or constants. If you want to set some default settings then assign your variables with initial values that will act as your default settings and later you can change them.

Answer (score 2):

All instance properties must be initialized in the `init` method. You can either move the initialization to the `init` (`defaultMode` would be your default value if `userDefaults` is nil):

```
init() {
  fanMode = (userDefaults?.valueForKey(Consts.kStoredFanMode) as? FanMode) ?? defaultMode
}
```

Set a default value for that property, for example:

```
var fanMode: FanMode = defaultMode
```

Or you can make your fanMode nullable:

```
var fanMode: FanMode? = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an implicity unwrapped optional. Just add a `!` to the variable declaration.

```
class ApplicationManager {

var fanMode: FanMode! //Implicitly unwrapped optional.

init()
{
  self.applyDefaultSettings()
}

func applyDefaultSettings()
{
  if let unwrappedFanMode = userDefaults.valueForKey(Consts.kStoredFanMode) as? FanMode {
    self.fanMode = unwrappedFanMode
  }
}

}
```

Basically it tricks xCode into telling it "Hey this variable is initialized and value will never be nil". But you want to be careful using these as if it does turn out to be nil your program will crash. But in your case it should be fine since you initialize it in the init method so it will never be nil before using it.

Comment: In the example given this direct initialization might have been the right choice, but if you want your applyDefaultSettings() function to depend on a parameter passed into the init function you'd be lost. Your answer provides the right answer here and prevents code duplication. I did think that if swift wanted to be so strict it should also do the inference and check if maybe all stored properties are initialized in applyDefaultSettings(). But then a function can be overriden and stuff would still fail.... Anyway good answer!